# How to trace a C++ program by hand?

Tags: c++, increment, decrement, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
#include<iostream>
int fun(int &x,int y=10)
{
 if(x%y==0)
  return (++x);
 else
  return (y--);
}
int main()
{
 int p=10,q=13;
 q=fun(p,q);
 cout<<p<<q<<endl;
 q=fun(q);
 cout<<p<<q<<endl;
 q=fun(p);
 cout<<p<<q<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

The output as shown is as follows:

```
1013
1010
1111
```

But when I try to solve it using pen and paper I am stuck. Please show me how to arrive at the correct output so as to keep my concepts clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p=10  q=13

1st call 
   p= 10 , q = 13
   p is passed by reference

returned will be y-- since it is post decrement it will return 13

2nd call

q = 13
   passed by ref
   x = 13 y =10

return will be y-- which is =10 not 9 since it is post

now p = 10 and q =10

3rd call
   x = 10 and y =10 by default 
   return ++x  and x = 11 ,so q=11,now since its is call by ref x =11 so  p=11 and

Comment: How is q=10 in the second call .q is passed by referenced but is not modified in the function definition.Is is because y-- is returning 10 ?

Comment: Thats because in 2nd call we r not passing any second argument , so accordingly default value in function definition will be used.

Comment: Thanks @JaspreetSingh .That helped :)